# Convert JToken into a JArray

Tags: c#, json

I want to know whats the best way to achieve this:-

```
JToken value = { "test":123", "test2":"456" } ( its in for each loop ).
```

I need to convert this into a JArray so it should look like:-

```
["Test:123"]
["Test2:456"]
```

Comment: Sounds x-y-ish. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please show us your attempts? Aslo what library do you use?  Is it Json.NET?

Comment: @GuruStron I am using JSON.Net. I have tried to do something like :-  var test = data.SelectToken("value")?.ToObject<JArray>();

Comment: @Fildor basically I have a Jtoken that contains two values. I want to convert these two values into a JArray.

Comment: Wouldn't your JArray look like `["Test:123", "Test2:456"]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Alberto's answer but with a slightly different cast for the enumeration.

```
var jsonToken = JToken.Parse("{ \"test\":\"123\", \"test2\":\"456\" }");
var jsonArray = new JArray();

foreach (JProperty prop in jsonToken)
{
    jsonArray.Add($"{prop.Name}:{prop.Value}");
}

Console.WriteLine(jsonArray);
```

Outputs (hopefully this is what you wanted)

```
[
  "test:123",
  "test2:456"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite understanding what you are trying to achieve but here is a starting point:

```
var jt = JToken.Parse("{ \"test\":\"123\", \"test2\":\"456\" }");
    
var ja = new JArray();
    
foreach(var k in jt)
{
    ja.Add(k.ToString());
}
    
Console.WriteLine(ja);
```